# Error:Attribute name "xmlns:" associated with an element type "manifest" must be followed by the ' = ' character

Tags: android, android-manifest

```
Error:Attribute name "xmlns:" associated with an element type "manifest" must be followed by the ' = ' character.
```

I just started to create games, so I don't clearly understand why it happened. When I created my previous game I had practically the similar manifest file without errors.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.snappik.memorise.Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.snappik.memorise.MemoriaStart"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.snappik.memorise.MemoRiseActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.snappik.memorise.MemoRiseActivityMedium"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.snappik.memorise.MemoRiseActivityHard"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.snappik.memorise.DifficultController"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.snappik.memorise.Settings"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.snappik.memorise.Records"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.snappik.memorise.RecordPoint"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.snappik.memorise.RecordTime"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.snappik.memorise.RecordsMedium"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.snappik.memorise.RecordsPointMedium"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.snappik.memorise.RecordsTimeMedium"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.snappik.memorise.RecordsHard"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.snappik.memorise.RecordsPointHard"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.snappik.memorise.RecordsTimeHard"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.snappik.memorise.RecordController"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your manifest file surrounded by the  tag?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="...">
</manifest>
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.snappik.memorise"
    android:platformBuildVersionCode="21"
    android:platformBuildVersionName="5.0.1-1624448"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >